# Estimate the number of certain fractions

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

I am able to estimate the quantity
$$
N(x) = \sum_{\substack{(a,b)=1\\1\leq ab\leq x}}1 = \sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{\substack{(a,b)=1\\ab=n}} 1.
$$
For this, I started observing that the inner sum is $2^{\omega(n)}=\sum_{d\mid n} \mu^2(d)$, where $\mu$ is the Moebius function. Then by using standard tools (average order of $\mu^2$, Abel partial summation, ...) I got $N(x) = \frac 6{\pi^2}x\log x + O(x)$.

Unfortunately I have no idea about how to estimate
$$
N(x,y) = \sum_{\substack{(a,b)=1\\1\leq ab\leq x\\\frac ab\leq y}}1 = \sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{\substack{(a,b)=1\\ab=n\\\frac ab\leq y}} 1,
$$
where $0\leq y\leq 1$. Some ideas:

- to derive $\sum_{\substack{(a,b)=1\\ab=n}} 1 = 2^{\omega(n)}$ I noticed that the sum is the number of divisors $a$ of $n$ such that $a$ and $\frac na$ do not share any common factor, which is in turn the number of ways of choosing a subset of the prime distinct factors of $n$;
- the two conditions $ab=n$ and $\frac ab\leq y$ implies $a\leq \sqrt{ny}$, so that I should count the divisors of $n$ such that $a$ and $\frac na$ do not share any common factor and such that $a\leq \sqrt{ny}$, but this seems to be difficult to express in terms of subsets of the prime factors of $n$.

I am thus not able to adapt the ideas used to estimate $N(x)$ to something useful for $N(x,y)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you ignore the relatively prime constraint, you can use area to get reasonable bounds. Call tha $M(x,y)$. You can recursively define the number of pairs by noticing that $M(x,y)=\sum_k N(x/k^2,y)$. By mapping $(a,b)$ to $(k,a/k,b/k)$ where $k=gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. If I understood correctly, you mean that I can estimate $M(x,y)$ with the area $\int_1^{\sqrt{xy}} (\frac xa - \frac ay)\,da = \frac 12 (x\log xy-x+\frac 1y)$ below the hyperbola $ab=x$ and above the line $b=\frac 1y a$. We also have $M(x,y)=\sum_{k\mid a} N(x/k^2,y)$, but I don't know how to proceed here to estimate $N$. Could you please clarify your argument?

Comment: Sorry, the last sum I wrote is not over $k\mid a$. It is just over $k$.

Comment: The largest term on the right side is $N(x,y)$. Reversing the formula, gives a formula for $N(x,y)$ in terms of smaller $N$ and $M(x,y)$. You can recursively calculate or estimate $N(x,/k^2,y)$ for all $k$.